# Copy constructor, pointers, true or false questions in C++ code

Tags: c++, pointers, copy

I'm knew to C++ so if anyone could help me out with these TorF questions it would be great.

**True or False:** Using C++, the copy constructor for a class is only used when passing by value to a function input.

**True or False:** The following C++ function `madeA()` is a valid function implementation.

```
ClassA{
public:
    int x;
    char *y;
};
void madeA(const A &t_a){
    t_a.x = 1;
    t_a.y = 0;
}
```

**True or False**: The following C++ code segments are equivalent.

```
void cmax(int a, int b, int *max){
    if(a>b) *ax = a;
    *max = b;
}

using namespace std;

void main(){
    int *max = new int;
    cmax(20, 5, max);
    cout<< *ax << endl;
}
```

next code:

```
void cmax(int a, int b, int &max){
    if(a>b) max = a;
    max = b;
}

void(){
    int max;
    cmax(20, 5, ax);
    std::cout <<max<<std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Could you at least tell us what you think and why?

Comment: 1st: Don't know what "passing by value means" so can't answer.
2nd: Ran it in a compiler and was giving me that "const" in the madA function was wrong. 
3rd: Didn't see a difference other than pointer use. 
Just wanted a better explanation for all of these to better understand the answers.

Answer (score 1):

**First: False**.
The copy constructor might be invoked anytime a copy is needed.
Simple example: return by value

**Second: False**.
You are modifying contents of a reference to `const` argument. It shouldn't compile and even if you use some pointer hackery it would result in **Undefined Behavior**.

**Third: False**.
First has a memory leak second doesn't.
The second code snippet won't even compile.

Comment: Technically, I wouldn't call it a memory leak. It's only one integer being allocated, which is cleaned up right after, when the program ends. If it was in a loop, then yes, I'd say it is.

Comment: i just got the second code on the third question to compile. Thanks for the answers though. Didn't understand why but now i do.

Comment: also the answer sheet says the first one is True

Comment: @chris: Its a finite leak scenario and not a recurring leak & yes the definition of a memory leak in this context is open for interpretation. But, One would expect the finite leak scenario to be used when it is really needed in this situation there is absolutely no reason to not call the `delete`.Also, if instead of `int` the data type would be a custom class who's destructor produces side effects then not calling `delete` would be UB so its best practice to call it.

Comment: @AlokSave, Very valid points. Mine was that you can argue a case to intentionally not free a large amount of memory at the end of the program because it causes the program to hang for a few seconds before closing, rather than the OS reclaiming the memory itself after the program finishes. As you pointed out, there is no reason to do so here.

Comment: @ddwong, The first one could be true in the context of C++03 with only passing arguments. It is most definitely not true in the general sense.  `MyClass a; MyClass b(a); //copy-constructor`